# Running Django test on project database

Tags: django

In my Django project, loading all the model instances into a new test database takes too much time. Is it possible for my test modules to run against the same project database (project_db) instead of the test database (test_project_db), since the same I will be querying identical model instances?

Comment: dont your tests run against a test database, that is created from scratch every time you run your test suite? IMHO it's a bad idea to run a test suite against a production database...

Comment: Running your tests against a production database is suicide. Please don't do that.

Comment: @benzkji - Well yes, as of now the tests are running against a test database. Unfortunately, running tests everytime means that the data needs to be loaded into the database from scratch, which takes around 50 minutes. Running against a production database would fix that.

Comment: @Brandon - Why exactly is testing against a production database "suicide"? I'm kinda new to Django, so not really aware of all the potential pitfalls.

Comment: You can also look into [`django-nose`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose) which features an option to reuse your DB between tests and has a feature called `fast fixtures`. The final test run should always go against a fresh database, but while continuously working on the tests it can speed things up.

Comment: What test data are you putting into your test database that makes it take 50 minutes to fill? that seems like the real problem to me. Also, you probably don't need to refill it every time. Just have a seperate test database prepared

Comment: For one, running tests puts added strain on the database, two, you don't want to take the chance of tests altering production data and three, tests fail and could potentially leave your database in an unusable state, borking your entire app **in production**

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest that you write tests that dont need the complete production database. You can create fixtures to have initial data (as much as you need, but not as much as you have in your prod db for sure). Or use tools like [mixer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mixer) and [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock). and yes, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose/ as sthzg suggests (fast fixtures!) is also worth a try.

as @Brandon said, "running your tests against a production database is suicide" is quite true. One error in your code can ruin your production database. Also, having fixtures and consistent data will give your reliable test results, whereas a production db will always change, and tests could break out of nothing, while you dont know why at all.

Comment: The statement about consistency is **absolutely vital** to proper testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're careful to write independent tests then the `--keep-db` flag may give you the speed-up you need without putting your production data in danger:

```
~ $ django-admin.py help test

[snip]

optional arguments:

[snip]

  -k, --keepdb          Preserves the test DB between runs.

[snip]
```